# Check size and then perform operation - is it safe for ConcurrentLinkedDeque?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, deque

I need to replace the first value in `Deque` with the new value, only
if the size will exceed the limit. I wrote this code to solve it:

```
final class Some {
    final int buffer;
    final Deque<Operation> operations = new ConcurrentLinkedDeque<>();
    // constructors ommited;

    @Override
    public void register(final Operation operation) {
        if (this.operations.size() == this.buffer) {
            // remove the oldest operation
            this.operations.removeFirst();
        }
        // add new operation to the tail
        this.operations.addLast(operation);
    }

    @Override
    public void apply() {
        // take the fresh operation from tail and perform it
        this.operations.removeLast().perform();
    }
}
```

As you see, I have two methods, that modifies the `Deque`. I have doubts, that this code will work correctly in the multithreaded environment. The question is: is it safe to check the `size()` and then performing operations, that modifies the `ConcurrentLinkedDeque` afterward? I want to have as least locks as possible. So if this code won't work, then I had to introduce locking and then there is no point in the usage of `ConcurrentLinkedDeque()`.

```
final class Some {
    final int buffer;
    final Deque<Operation> operations = new LinkedList<>();
    final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    // constructors ommited;

    @Override
    public void register(final Operation operation) {
        this.lock.lock();
        try {
            if (this.operations.size() == this.buffer) {
                // remove the oldest operation
                this.operations.removeFirst();
            }
            // add new operation to the tail
            this.operations.addLast(operation);
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void apply() {
        this.lock.lock();
        try {
            // take the fresh operation from tail and perform it
            this.operations.removeLast().perform();
        } finally {
            this.lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the alternative with the `Lock`. Is that the only way to achieve what I want? I am especially interested in trying to use the concurrent collections.

Comment: No, the non-`Lock` example would not be safe in a multi-threaded environment. Checking-then-acting is not atomic without outside synchronization. Also, unless you aren't allowed to add `Operation`s while one is running I wouldn't call `perform()` while still holding the `Lock`.

Comment: In addition, `ConcurrentLinkedDeque#size()` requires a full scan and may vary due to concurrent adds / removals. You'll likely fair best using `ArrayDeque` and your locking code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concurrent collections are thread-safe when it comes to *internal* state. In other words, they

- Allow multiple threads to read/write concurrently without having to worry that the internal state will become corrupted
- Allow iteration and removal while other threads are modifying the collection

  - Not all, however. I believe `CopyOnWriteArrayList`'s `Iterator` does not support the `remove()` operation
- Guarantees things such as *happens-before*

  - Meaning a write by one thread will *happen-before* a read by a subsequent thread

However, they are *not* thread-safe *across* external method calls. When you call one method it will acquire whatever locks are necessary but those locks are released by the time the method returns. If you're not careful this can lead to a *check-then-act* race condition. Looking at your code

```
if (this.operations.size() == this.buffer) {
    this.operations.removeFirst();
}
this.operations.addLast(operation);
```

the following can happen:

1. `Thread-A` checks size condition, result is `false`
2. `Thread-A` moves to add new `Operation`
3. Before `Thread-A` can add the `Operation`, `Thread-B` checks size condition which results in `false` as well
4. `Thread-B` goes to add new `Operation`
5. `Thread-A` *does* add new `Operation`

   - Oh, no! The `Operation` added by `Thread-A` causes the size threshold to be reached
6. `Thread-B`, already past the `if` statement, adds its `Operation` making the deque have one too many `Operation`s

This is why a *check-then-act* requires external synchronization, which you do in your second example using a `Lock`. Note you could also use a `synchronized` block on the `Deque`.

Unrelated to your question: You call `Operation.perform()` in your second example while still holding the `Lock`. This means no other thread can attempt to add another `Operation` to the `Deque` while `perform()` executes. If this isn't desired you can change the code like so:

```
Operation op;

lock.lock();
try {
    op = deque.pollLast(); // poll won't throw exception if there is no element
} finally {
    lock.unlock();
}

if (op != null) {
    op.perform();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the doc of size()

> BlockquoteBeware that, unlike in most collections, this method is NOT a constant-time operation. Because of the asynchronous nature of these deques, determining the current number of elements requires traversing them all to count them. Additionally, it is possible for the size to change during execution of this method, in which case the returned result will be inaccurate. Thus, this method is typically not very useful in concurrent applications.

While @Slaw is correct, also add that an addition/subtraction can occur during the traversal.

I don't use size() in my software. I keep my own count of what is in the collection with an AtomicInteger. If count.get() < max, I can add. Being a little over max is ok for my  usage. You can use a lock on count to force compliance.